# are "rent" and "hire" used correctly in these sentences?

Tags: difference

(1) I rented my pencil to my friend with 2$ per hour for 3 hours <=> (2) my friend hired a pencil from me with 2$ per hour for 3 hours

(3) he hires a girl to be his girlfriend at this weekend

(4) they hired a house for 4 hours

Comment: 1 - You *rent* when you pay, you **rent out** when get paid. 2 - You don't hire objects, only people or maybe a plowhorse. So 4 - They rented it for 4 hours.

Comment: Yosef Baskin tks for your support

Comment: @YosefBaskin Here in Britain, we can hire objects; there are businesses that do car hire, tool hire, plant hire (such as construction equipment etc), boat hire. You hire them, they hire them out. By the hour, day, week, or whatever. Almost certainly in other BrE zones like Australia & New Zealand. Where Americans say 'hire' (as in 'hire and fire') we say 'employ' or 'recruit'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's really interesting! In that case, would you be hiring the object? Or the people to operate/staff the object? Like in the US you might "hire" a taxi, but really that means that you're hiring the taxi driver to operate the taxi itself. Or if I said that I'm hiring a snowplow, it means that I'm hiring a snowplow driver who will bring a plow to remove snow from my road/driveway.

Comment: If that's not the case, and you can "hire" a boat/car/etc. without any people attached to the object, is there any rule about which objects can be "hired" and which must be "rented" or "leased"? Or are the words interchangeable? Could I hire an office building for my company?

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon - in the UK, we **hire** objects (pay money to borrow them for a fixed time), That means I pay the company a deposit, sign a hire agreement, and take the item away and use it for some purpose. When I have finished I take it back in good condition and get my deposit back, minus a charge for each day I kept it.  I could also hire or employ someone to drive the van, dig the holes, cut the stone slabs, etc, but I'd probably just hire or employ a company to do the whole thing.

Comment: This is editing which is disallowed here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Context, I'm American, so my answer might not be applicable to other dialects as Michael pointed out.)

### Hire vs Rent

As noted in the comments, in American English, you *rent* or *lease* objects/property and *hire* people. There are some exceptions to this rule, but that's typically the case.

### Question 1 & 2

I would say - **I rented my pencil to my friend for 3 hours at $2/hour.** Notes about this:

- This is an object, so we would use the word *rent* not the word hire. The word *loan* would also work in this case.
- To *rent* can mean both "to pay money for temporary use" and "to charge money for temporary use" so either person in the exchange can use the word *rent*. The difference is in the prepositions. Here, we say "I rented my pencil *to* my friend." We could also say "My friend rented a pencil *from* me." They have the same meaning.
- The preposition *with* doesn't work here. When talking about money, we typically use the prepositions *for* or *at*, *for* also works for duration. So we could say *"I rented my pencil to my friend for $2/hour."* or *"I rented my pencil to my friend for 3 hours."* When we need to combine both pieces of information, it sounds weird to say *"I rented my pencil to my friend for $2/hours for 3 hours."* so instead I put them together with the preposition *at* before the rate ($2/hour) instead. [Here's a video about money prepositions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgyQlWrNDAM) if you'd like to learn more.
- When talking about US dollars, the dollar sign goes before the number *$2* instead of *2$*. Wikipedia says:

> In the United States, Mexico, Australia, Argentina, New Zealand, Hong
> Kong, Pacific Island nations, and English-speaking Canada, the sign is
> written before the number ("$5"), even though the word is written or
> spoken after it ("five dollars", "cinco pesos"). In French-speaking
> Canada, exceptionally, the dollar symbol usually appears after the
> number,[24] e.g., "5$". (The cent symbol is written after the number
> in most countries that use it, e.g., "5¢".)

### Question 3

I would say **"He hired a girl to pretend to be his girlfriend this weekend."** or **"He will hire a girl to pretend to be his girlfriend this weekend."** (depending on whether the girl has already been hired or not). Notes about this:

- We use *hire* because this is a person, not an object.
- The simple present tense (*he hires*) would imply that this is something he does repeatedly or regularly, which doesn't make sense when we say a specific time (*this weekend*). Instead, we could use the past tense (*he hired*), the future tense (*he will hire*) or the present progressive (*he is hiring*).
- I added the words *to pretend*. A girlfriend in the US is an emotional relationship and impossible to pay someone to actually fill. At best, saying that someone is hiring a girlfriend would imply that they are hiring a prostitute to have sex with. But that wouldn't actually fit the definition of "girlfriend." Instead, I would assume that this person was hiring someone to fake being his girlfriend.
- When talking about duration and time, we would use the prepositions *for* in this case, not *at*.

### Question 4

I would say **"They rented a house for 4 hours."** Notes about this:

- Since this is property, it doesn't make a lot of sense to "*hire*" it. Instead, we can *"rent"* it.

Comment: tks for your detailed answers. They are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

None of these are particularly idiomatic.

In British English you can "hire" a person to do a job (permanently or temporarily).  You can "hire" an object by paying for temporary use of that object. You can rent property to become a tenant, you can "rent-out" property as a landlord. And you can rent an object, paying to use it temporarily, essentially the same meaning as hire.

So

> The school has hired a new English teacher.

> I hired a car for the weekend.

> I rented an apartment for six months.

> I rented out my house when I was posted overseas.

> I rented a car for the weekend.

But you wouldn't rent or hire something trivial like a pencil, except as a joke.

You can hire a prostitute (or a "rent boy") to pretend to be your girlfriend/boyfriend but you can't hire someone to actually be a girlfriend.

You can't rent a house for a few hours, because you don't become a tenant.  It has to be for a longer period of time.

Comment: if "rent" and "hire" are not acceptable, can we use "lend" and "borrow"?. For example, I lend my book to my friend at 2$ per hour

Comment: $2 not 2$ ... Yes but it doesn't seem very realistic.  Do people in your country demand money from a friend who wants to borrow a book for a few hours?  In my country that would not be culturally acceptable.

Comment: Sometimes I do, but it is just a joke :))). tks a lot for your help